# After upgrade to fios and G3100 router, wireless printer no longer connects

Tags: wifi, printing, cups, router, slackware

I'm running slackware64-current (current distro downloaded 9/1/19) and using a brother HL-L2395DW printer. And up until 7/28/20, my internet was verizon dsl using a westell 6100 modem/router. I used the 6100 as a router, and a linksys wrt120n with its router function disabled as a wireless wap. And the hll2395 was connecting and printing fine with that setup for several years (and ditto with an earlier brother printer before that).

But verizon's "copper retirement" forced what they're calling a "mandatory upgrade" to fios, whereby the westell 6100 is gone, replaced by verizon's G3100. And I can either use the G3100's wireless, or turn that off and continue using the wrt120n. And everything seems to be working fine either way, **>>except printing<<** (And, yes, I entered the G3100's new essid and key at the printer's control panel:)...

Laptops pick up both the G3100's and the wrt120n's wireless. And **>>even the scanner on the hll2395dw works fine<<** both ways. Running xsane immediately picks up the scanner, and documents scan fine. But when trying to print anything, including a test page, both cups and   lpstat -p   just say "Connecting to printer" forever and ever. But I can point my browser to the printer's ip address, and that all seems fine, as far as I can tell.

The most I could get out of google was some security issue, whereby I lowered the G3100's security to "low" and rebooted. But no help. And the G3100 network page shows the printer connected regardless of security setting. And there's also a page where you can "test connectivity", which always reports "success". And the printer's control panel also shows a blue light indicating that it's connected.

Finally, just to test the hardware, I connected the printer via usb, and re-installed it to cups. And that immediately printed and scanned perfectly. So at this point I'm stymied -- everything seems to be set up and connected as it should be, but it just doesn't want to work. "Connecting to printer" is all it ever says. Suggestions about what to try next appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally googled an answer to the problem that actually works, and is extremely simple...

When running the linux-brprinter-installer-... printer install tool, it asks for the DeviceURI, which I'd always just specified (choice#10) as

```
DeviceURI lpd://BRWEC5C68323304/BINARY_P1
```

which is the typical cups default when adding a printer directly through cups at localhost:631. And that had always worked, for several different wifi Brother printers and several different routers. It's only with the G3100 that I ran into the problem described above.

Some anonymous poster that I finally found with google suggested that when the installer asks for DeviceURI, instead specify (choice#11) the ip address:

```
DeviceURI socket://192.168.1.47
```

(using your own IP address, of course). And that immediately worked.

Why it now works with `socket://` and no longer works with `lpd://` is beyond my ken (and not explained by the googled poster). Not that it really matters, but just curious: anybody have any ideas about that???